# Find objects in a list that extend a certain class

Tags: java

In my game, all game objects extend an Entity class. All enemy objects have their own class which extend Enemy. Enemy extends Entity.
In other words,
Entity -> Enemy -> SharkEnemy.

Now, I want to have a function to let me test for collision against a specific class.
That is, if for example I have a bullet class, I want it to only test for collision against entities that extend Enemy.

I've googled around and this is what I have:

```
public <T> Entity collide(Entity a, Class<T> desiredClass)
{

    for (Entity b : entities)
        if (b.getClass() == desiredClass && collide(a, b))
            return b;
    return null;
}
```

That is kind of what I want, but I need to know if it extends desiredClass, not if the class equals desiredClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking for class equality, use [`Class.isAssignableFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

```
 public <T> Entity collide(Entity a, Class<T> desiredClass)
 {

     for (Entity b : entities)
         if (desiredClass.isAssignableFrom( b.getClass() ) && collide(a, b))
             return b;
     return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're passing in the class object,

```
for (Entity b: entities)
{
  if (SharkEnemy.class.isInstance(b)...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in (T desiredType) rather than a class and use:

```
if (b instanceof desiredType)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get your exact problem but couldn't you just use interfaces and polymorphism? I would look like a better design choice without any use of RTTI

For example:

```
abstract class Entity
{
  abstract boolean isCollidingWithBullet(Bullet bullet);
  .. concrete methods ..
}

class Enemy extends Entity
{
  boolean isCollidingWithBullet(Bullet bullet)
  {
    .. specific implementation
  }
}

class NotEnemy extends Entity
{
  boolean isCollidingWithBullet(Bullet bullet)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```